# referencing a div from javascript - jsfiddle failing

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to update a div in an html file with images by referencing the div with a container and then appending image tags to it. This is as shown below:

```
var linksContainer = $('#links');

var thisURL = document.URL;         

//check if there is a id or not
if(thisURL.indexOf('?') === -1)
{    
//no '?' found therefore all photos in "data" are added to the gallery

//then add these photos one by one
for (i = 0; i < data.count; i++) 
         { //count parameter has been set up as the number of photos

            //selecting the i-th photo in the list of photos
            dataPhoto = data.photos[i];

            //then add these photos one by one
             $('<a/>').append($('<img>')
             .prop('src', dataPhoto.photo_file_url))
             .prop('title', dataPhoto.photo_title)
             .attr('data-gallery', '')
             .appendTo(linksContainer);
        }
}
```

where the html is simply
    `<div id="links"></div>`

I did a jsfiddle and noticed that it is failing on the first line - but the rest of the code works as expected, why can't I reference a div in this way?

NB: I am using the bootstrap-image-gallery and have edited the code which is used in the demo, seen here: https://github.com/blueimp/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/blob/master/js/demo.js - where the part that I am editing is instead of adding the images from flickr I am adding them from a local resource.

Comment: can you show your jsfiddle?

Comment: Can we see this JSFiddle? Were you certain to include a version of jQuery as a library?

Comment: Of course;

https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=6G8u3vBNhz

The "data.json" file is simply in the format shown below

var data = { "count": 5, "photos": [
{"photo_id": 1, etc etc..}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/euj1m652/) that shows your code should work.

```
var linksContainer = $('#links');
var data={count:1, photos:[{photo_file_url:'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png',photo_title:"asd"}]};

for (i = 0; i < data.count; i++) { 
    var dataPhoto = data.photos[i];    
    $('<a/>').append($('<img>').prop('src', dataPhoto.photo_file_url))
    .prop('title', dataPhoto.photo_title)
    .attr('data-gallery', '')
    .appendTo(linksContainer);
}
```

If it's not working outside of the fiddle, make sure the javascript is executed after the links element has been created. The most common way of doing that is putting the script tag as the last element inside the body tag.